# Javascript regex match string in paragraph excluding urls

Tags: javascript, regex

Using javascript in the client I want to match a search term in a paragraph, but exclude any matches that are part of a URL.

I've tried this regex below, but getting an error: * A quantifier inside a lookbehind makes it non-fixed width

```
(?<!(http:|https).*)Driving
```

Sample text:

```
<small><span class="link-small">&gt;&gt;8833079</span></small><br />Do you think driving is fun?<br /> hi<br /> http://www.driving.com
```

I want to match the first "driving" but not the second, which is part of a URL.

Thanks

Comment: You haven't used the regex in JS, only in the regex tester, have you? Anyway, although the pattern [works in JS](https://regex101.com/r/RFBwSN/1),  it is wrong. Why don't you parse the HTML and run the regex on the plain text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to eliminate all HTML tags first, then remove all links within the plain text, so finally you can perform a search within the rest of the plain text.

---

**Example:**

```
String.prototype.toText = function(){
    return $(html).text();
};

var text = html.toText();
text = text.replace(/\bhttps?:\/\/\S+/gi, '');
```

---

See a simple demo at https://jsfiddle.net/dtc0gq1r/

Comment: Good idea. To simplify, I would use this simple regex `<[^>]+>` to remove the tags. We don't know if jQuery is available or not.

Comment: @StephaneJanicaud - Your simplifying is risky - imagine for example tag `<img id="captcha" alt="Is 2+5>7 ?" id="driving" src="http://example.org/captcha.png?12345">`